# DB2 AUDIT - LOAD into audit table

Tags: db2, load, audit, lob

I'm trying to audit a specific User and created a audit policy which i assigned to to User. I then archived and extracted the audit data.

So far so good.

I then used the db2audit.dll to create the tables needed.

```
TABNAME  TABSCHEMA
-------- ---------
AUDIT    AUDIT
CHECKING AUDIT
CONTEXT  AUDIT
EXECUTE  AUDIT
OBJMAINT AUDIT
SECMAINT AUDIT
SYSADMIN AUDIT
VALIDATE AUDIT
```

And now I've got a problem loading the data into the table.

This is the statement I'm using (from the Knowledge Center):

db2 "LOAD from execute.del of DEL MODIFIED BY DELPRIORITYCHAR LOBSINFILE INSERT INTO AUDIT.EXECUTE"

When I execute this statement nothing happens.

The diaglog only shows the following until I CRTL+C the Statement:

```
2017-03-01-18.17.10.369493+060 I4839757A617         LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 6619308              TID : 46267          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2xxx               NODE : 000           DB   : XXX
APPHDL  : 0-61914              APPID: *LOCAL.db2xxx.170301163935
AUTHID  : DB2XXX               HOSTNAME: axxxxxxxx
EDUID   : 46267                EDUNAME: db2agent (XXX) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluvtld_route_in, probe:924
DATA #1 : LOADID, PD_TYPE_LOADID, 50 bytes
LOADID: 46267.2017-03-01-18.17.10.369444.0 (-1;-1)
DATA #2 : String, 55 bytes
Starting LOAD operation (S) (1) (I) [AUDIT   .EXECUTE].
```

I really don't know what I'm missing here.

Thanks,

Mirko

Comment: LOAD doesn't report errors until it finishes, and each error results in a slowdown – if there are lots of errors you can experience the behavior you're seeing.  I'd suggest adding `warningcount 50` into your LOAD statement (to force LOAD to fail if there are 50 warnings).

Comment: There were no warnings but thanks for this hint... it led me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself...

Since I'm working in a SAP Enviroment there are no 8K Tablespaces. All the Tablespaces and Bufferpools are 16K.

After looking into the ddl-File I found this in the comment section.

```
  --   -> assumes an 8K tablespace is available for use
```

(I have to admit I didn't read the Knowledge Center properly. There is a short sentence mentioning the required 8K Tablespace) :)

After creating an 8K bufferpool, 8K tablespace and drop/create the tables the LOAD worked just fine.

Comment: This doesn't really jive with what you described in your question.  Either AUDIT.EXECUTE existed or not.  If it did not exist (i.e. because `create table` failed), you would have received an error (`SQL3304N  The table does not exist.`) when issuing the LOAD command.

Comment: The CREATE TABLE did not fail and the script (sqllib/misc/db2audit.ddl) just works fine even though there is no 8K tablespace.